# How to use z axis value in accelerometer android?

Tags: android, andengine, accelerometer

i am using `andengine` for implementing `accelerometer` sensor in android. my requirement is i have to move the ball to the center of the screen using accelerometer. I am able to achieve that when the device is in lying flat position. because it uses the X and Y acceleration values for the calculation in `AndEngine` library.

but the problem arise when i hold the device in straight up position. the object doesn't move to the center and it always lays down to the bottom bar of the screen. however, i tried to calculate the z value at this time and inject my logic into `AccelerationData` class to use z value instead of y. but no success. please go through the following code and guide me what wrong i am doing.

**AccelerationData.java**

```
public class AccelerationData extends BaseSensorData {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final IAxisSwap AXISSWAPS[] = new IAxisSwap[4];

static {
    AXISSWAPS[Surface.ROTATION_0] = new IAxisSwap() {
        @Override
        public void swapAxis(final float[] pValues) {
            final float x = -pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X];
            final float y;
            if(SensorManager.DATA_Z > -0.50 && SensorManager.DATA_Z <0.50){
                y = pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Z];
            }else{
                y = pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
            }
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X] = x;
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y] = y;
        }
    };

    AXISSWAPS[Surface.ROTATION_90] = new IAxisSwap() {
        @Override
        public void swapAxis(final float[] pValues) {
            final float x = pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
            final float y = pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X];
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X] = x;
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y] = y;
        }
    };

    AXISSWAPS[Surface.ROTATION_180] = new IAxisSwap() {
        @Override
        public void swapAxis(final float[] pValues) {
            final float x = pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X];
            final float y = -pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X] = x;
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y] = y;
        }
    };

    AXISSWAPS[Surface.ROTATION_270] = new IAxisSwap() {
        @Override
        public void swapAxis(final float[] pValues) {
            final float x = -pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
            final float y = -pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X];
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_X] = x;
            pValues[SensorManager.DATA_Y] = y;
        }
    };
}
...
...
}
```

here i am showing the usage of z value only when device is at 0 degree. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here is full tutorial on how to use accelerometer data in android http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/